# Check if there are any duplicated orders

Tags: sql, sqlite, group-by, count

Hi I have three tables customers, contacts and order. I need to check if there are duplicates (wrongly entered orders) in the table orders. If yes I need to return the first and last name from table customer, email from table contact and finally order and order id.

I want to check these duplicates by finding more orders with the same order_id.

[image]

Comment: This is not a valid aggregation query. Also, how do *you* define a "duplicate order"? An explanation, along with sample data and desired results, would be helpful.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: What if you have twice the same `order_id` with two different `customer_id`s?

Comment: Actually the duplicates in order_id in this case always have only one customer_id.

Comment: Duplicate order for me would be two or more orders with the same order_id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to join this query also:

```
SELECT order_id, COUNT(*) counter FROM orders GROUP BY order_id HAVING counter > 1
```

which returns the duplicate `order_id`s and there is no need for additional aggregation:

```
SELECT DISTINCT c1.first_name, c1.last_name, c2.email, o.order_id, o.item, t.counter
FROM orders o
INNER JOIN (SELECT order_id, COUNT(*) counter FROM orders GROUP BY order_id HAVING counter > 1) t
ON t.order_id = o.order_id
LEFT JOIN customers c1  ON o.customer_id = c1.customer_id
LEFT JOIN contacts  c2  ON o.customer_id = c2.customer_id
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing sounds like:

```
having count(distinct o.order_id) > 1
```

EDIT:

You have a very strange data model with an `orders` table and a non-unique `order_id` in it.  Usually this is split into two tables, such as `orders` and `orderlines`.

In any case, you seem to want something like:

```
select o.order_id
from orders o
group by o.order_id
having count(*) > 1;
```

You can use this as a subquery and join in other information, such as about customers.

Comment: Dont know why but the result in not correct. My sample order table contains duplicated orders, you can see order id number 3 and 6 are twice ine the table. However they are not in the result. This is my code : `SELECT c1.first_name, c1.last_name, c2.email, o.order_id, o.item  FROM orders o
LEFT JOIN customers c1 ON o.customer_id = c1.customer_id
LEFT JOIN contacts c2 ON o.customer_id = c2.customer_id
GROUP BY o.customer_id
HAVING count (distinct o.order_id) > 1`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a window count to identify orders whose `order_id` occurs more than once in the `orders` table, then join the other tables:

```
select co.firstname, co.lastname, cu.email, o.order_id, o.item, o.cnt
from (
    select o.*, count(*) over(partition by oder_id) as cnt
    from orders o
) o
inner join customers cu  on cu.customer_id = c.customer_id
inner join contacts  co  on co.customer_id = c.customer_id
where o.cnt > 1
```